# Colors not mapping to folium colorpleth map

Tags: pandas, folium

I am trying to plot data from a file I created using folium to a US map. The colors are not plotting onto the map - the map is all black. The "Reported Cases" values range from 0 to 106.

```
`threshold_scale = [0, max * 0.25, max * 0.5, max * 0.75, max]

color_map.caption = 'Rate by State'

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name="choropleth",
    data=df,
    columns=["State", "Reported Cases"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color='BuPu',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=.1, 
    threshold_scale = threshold_scale,
    legend_name="Incidence Rate by State",

).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

# Add the color map to the map
m.add_child(color_map)
m.keep_in_front(color_map)`
```

[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!